# Redirect everything to index.php without changing url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am getting crazy trying to get this work. I am planning a rather complex redesign of my whole website. Since my website should work differently depending on which subfolder (e.g www.mydomain.com/test123) you try to access, I think the easiest solution would be to redirect every single request to a main index.php and handle all cases from there. I will also want to redirect images and css files etc. as I will handle those cases "manually" too.

Here exactly what it should do:

1. It should redirect every request to index.php in the root folder
2. It should pass everything after the first slash as a query param. (mydomain.com/test123 --> mydomain.com/index.php?q=test123)
3. This redirection should not be visible for the client. In the above example this means it should stay /test123 but the server
   should receive /index.php?q=test123

I have tried this but this wont work somehow...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 [P]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule should work for you in site root .htaccess:

```
DirectorySlash Off
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

No need to use `P` flag that is used for proxying and that requires `mod_proxy` to be enabled in Apache config.

Comment: Thanks, but it still displays /test?q=test, instead it should only show /test but still send a request to /index.php?q=test

Comment: Is `/test` a real directory? If not clear your browser cache and test in Chrome dev tool with caching disabled.

Comment: Yes it is a real directory, but just tried again with your updated code and it works perfectly fine! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -2):

You can use the include() function in php.

ex

```
<?php
include('www.google.com');
?>
```

Comment: Not exactly what i looked for